# String to Date and Time format with swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I have a String like "20170713 111326" and it should be changed to "13/07/2017" and "11:13 AM".What'll be the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

Try this code

```
let st = "20170713 111326"

let dateFmt = DateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HHmmss"

if let date = dateFmt.date(from: st) {

    dateFmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a"
    let finalDate = dateFmt.string(from: date))
}
```

Comment: this date format it is wrong. HH is for 00-23 hours. For 12h clock am/pm time (1-12) he needs to use lowercase `h` so the time part should be `h:mm a`

Comment: @Jaydeep,your code is definitely what I'm looking for. Thank you for your help. Thanks

Comment: @LeoDabus welcome, and if you found answer helpful you can accept answer so next time another user directly use it.